# Color points in tmap by date column

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I am trying to color a set of geographical points by a time variable using the `tmap` function `tm_dots`, but it keeps treating the time variable as a categorical variable. Is there a way to use a `POSIXct` column as a continuous variable? Some example code demonstrating the problem is:

```r
library(sf)
library(tmap)
df = data.frame(lon=1:20,lat=1:20,ts=as.POSIXct(paste0('2020-01-',1:20)))
df = st_as_sf(df,coords=c("lon","lat"),crs=4326)

tm_shape(df) + tm_dots(col="ts")
```

[image: Code output]

One "solution" would be to convert the dates into a number (e.g., number of days since the earliest date), and then use this numeric variable to color the points, perhaps using different labels in the legend to replace the numbers with the original dates, but this seems like a lot of work and is unlikely to produce satisfactory results without a lot of fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare a palette; for a possible approach consider this piece of code. What it does is it uses a generic sequential palette. Also note the silent default of `stretch.palette = TRUE` in a generic `tmap::tm_symbols()` call - this leads to interpolating colors, i.e. you can have more values than your palette has defined colors.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
df = data.frame(lon=1:20,lat=1:20,ts=as.POSIXct(paste0('2020-01-',1:20)))
df = st_as_sf(df,coords=c("lon","lat"),crs=4326)

tm_shape(df) + tm_dots(col="ts",
                       palette = "seq") # also consider "Blues"
```

[image: a plot with dots in sequiential palette]

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question as defining a palette will change the colors used to show the data, but looking at the legend it appears that the data is still being treated as a categorical variable. This will work OK if the dates are strictly linear without gaps as they are in the simple example I gave, but if you have dates with gaps and that are not simply dates, but also times, then this will not work as expected.

Comment: I am afraid this is as far as tmap will let us go; if you require the intensity of a color to map to a numeric variable you will be better off using `ggplot::geom_sf()` and map color to an aesthetic using ggplot techniques.

Comment: tmap will handle coloring by a numerical variable just fine. It is date variables that are problematic. Is this what you meant?